# Making application listen to port

Tags: virtualbox, port-forwarding

I am running an Ubuntu guest machine through my Windows 7 host machine (with Virtualbox), and on the Ubuntu system running an application that uses port 6969. Through configuring the Virtualbox port forwarding settings I have made it possible that I can go to 127.0.0.1:6969 in my browser and see the application's default page.

However, I'm wondering how I can port forward from my Windows 7 machine to the whole network. My local network (IPv4) address is 192.168.0.5. I want to be able to go to 192.168.0.5:6969 from any computer on the network and see the application.

I've searched Google but can only seem to find solutions in Linux, not Windows. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the same IP address on host and guest? How about setting up a network bridge to the guest (I don't know how in Windows) and let the guest get its own IP address via DHCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a port forwarding of port 6969/tcp from host to guest, either via the GUI or on the commandline (replace VM_NAME with the actual name of your VM).

```
VBoxManage modifyvm VM_NAME --natpf1 "webapp,tcp,,6969,,6969"
```